# When I use android studio the emulator gets struck at google logo

Tags: android, android-studio

This is the project I am using [github](https://github.com/circlefin/w3s-android-sample-app-wallets).

No matter what virtual device I create. I get the same result. It doesnt go after google logo. I have used android 8.1 and API 34

Physical device works but virtual doesnt.

I have created different devices, with and without google play. I have also looked on stack overflow but those solutions dont work.

Comment: This seems like a PC problem and not a github project problem. You should state your PC's CPU / OS / RAM / free storage space.